# Vue.js how to access component state/variables but keep encapsulation/hide from template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, encapsulation

Vue automatically exposes all `methods` to the template (using Options API) and all top-level variables (using Composition API).

If I need to access logic that is only internal to the script, but wants to hide/encapsulate that from the template, how can I achieve that?

In Angular for example, due to the OOP approach, you can just declare a method `private`, and Angular will not make that available to the HTML file.

Comment: How is it an issue? Don't use it if not needed.

Comment: It's not an issue, it's a matter of SOLID principles. I do not want to expose that method as it's not intended to be consumed within the template. It's about not exposing "implementation details" outside the boundaries of where the logic is used (the script tag).

Comment: I'm not sure that Vue has a such thing. CAPI methods are still [closed by default](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose). Then, it's a matter of using JS classes or alike. But I don't think that the framework has more to it from an encapsulation POV. VueJS is not heavy on OOP anyway.

Comment: " all top-level variables (using Composition API)." - this is not so. You're probably referring to script setup syntax, but then you should ask about it and not components in general. There may be no reason to distinguish a template and script. They are parts of a component, not separate entities

Comment: I agree with @EstusFlask "There may be no reason to distinguish a template and script". For me, script in component is only for "UI" coding, everything else is exported in separate files and imported as needed

Comment: Did you try the `expose` function? With that you are able to expose what you want. https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-setup.html#exposing-public-properties

Comment: @kissu @Leif Marcus thank you. Didn't mean accessible outside the instance. @Etus Flask observation is correct, I meant when using the `<script setup>` syntax or the `methods: {}` in the Options API.

Comment: If you want to hide the functions from the component, you could use a composable, that only returns the functionality that you need inside the component. This could be a workaround, but i don’t understand, why this is needed. You could also work with the setup function and return only needed variables and functions

Comment: Yes, I do agree your two options seem the most suitable solutions